# What does the notation $\overline{ \operatorname{span} M}$ represent?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

What does the notation $\overline { \operatorname{span} M}$ represent?

For example $M$ is total in $X$ if and only if $\overline { \operatorname{span} M}=X$

Comment: Closure of the span.

Comment: using \text{span} instead of \operatorname{span} was the reason for the conspicuous lack of proper spacing.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M = \{m_i : i \in I\}$ is any indexed set of vectors in the vector space $X$ over the field $F$, then the span of $M$ is the set of vectors 
$$\operatorname{span}M =\left\lbrace \sum_{i\in I} c_im_i : c_i \in F \text{ and all but finitely many } c_i\text{'s are zero}\right\rbrace.$$
It is the smallest vector subspace of $X$ which contains every vector in $M$. Subspaces are much nicer to work with than ordinary sets of vectors because they themselves are vector spaces over $F$.

In a normed vector space $(X,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$, there is a notion by which any sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ is said to "converge,'' namely there is some vector $L \in X$ such that the points in our sequence satisfy $$ \Vert x_n - L \Vert \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0.$$
If $M = \{m_i : i \in I\}$ is any set of vectors in $M$, then the closure of $M$ is the set
$$\overline{M} = \left\lbrace L \in X : \text{there is a sequence in } M \text{ converging to } L\right\rbrace, $$
and we say we are adding the "limit points" of $M$ to $M$.  Note that $M \subset \overline{M}$ because we can take constant sequences. Combining these two notions gives a definition of $\overline{\operatorname{span}M}.$